# Get source string from NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

is it possible to obtain somehow source string from NumberFormatException in catch clause eg.:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt("test");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.sourceString(); \\ to return "test"
}
```

Thanks.
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There is no *good* way to do what you ask; better to save the variable before the `try` block.

---

#### Long answer:

[Here's the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/NumberFormatException.java#NumberFormatException.forInputString%28java.lang.String%29) that creates the exception:

```
static NumberFormatException forInputString(String s) {
    return new NumberFormatException("For input string: \"" + s + "\"");
}
```

As you can see, the parse string is not stored in the exception, as it creates the error message as part of the constructor. However, because we always know the format, we could write something like this:

```
try {
  int foo = Integer.parseInt("foo");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  String message = e.getMessage();
  System.out.println(message.substring(19, message.length() - 1));
}
```

Therefore, as @chrylis said, storing the value in a variable before the `try` block and using it if there's an exception is the best solution.

Two reasons **not** to do it this way (which is really the only way to do what you've asked in the OP):

1. If they ever change the message, your code will break (this is still true of @EvgeniyDorofeev's answer)
2. This way is much slower as it has to parse the `String`

Answer (score 4):

Save it in a variable before the `try` block.

Comment: That is one option, but it does not solves the problem, where I want to generate proper error message with source string inside.

Comment: Unless you want to extend `NumberFormatException` (which will contain the parse string), and build a version of parseInt that throws that extended class; all of which is heavyweight, @chrylis solution is probably the best one.

Comment: So it is not possible to obtain it in some ellegant easy way from exception self.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String ss = e.getMessage();
ss = ss.substring(ss.indexOf('"') + 1, ss.length() - 1);
```